# How to Convert (null) values with 0 output in PIVOT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I tried to Replace the (null) values with 0 (zeros) output by Using PIVOT.

**Code below:**

```
declare @col as nvarchar(max),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @col = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Week) 
from pivote_created  group by Week order by Week FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
set @query =  'select * from ( select store, week, xCount from pivote_created ) src pivot (sum(xcount)for week in (' + @col + ')) piv';
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

**output**

```
store | 1  | 2  | 3   | 5
____________________________
101   | 138| 282| 220 | NULL
102   | 96 | 212| 123 | NULL
105   | 37 | 78 | NULL| 60
109   | 59 | 97 | 87  | NULL
```

**I would like this**

```
 store | 1   | 2   | 3   | 5
 ___________________________
 10    | 138 | 282 | 220 | 0
 102   | 96  | 212 | 123 | 0
 105   | 37  | 78  | 0   | 60
 109   | 59  | 97  | 87  | 0
```

Comment: i guess this is not Oracle db it should be tagged as SQL SERVER

Comment: In Oracle it's NVL() function but your code seems to be T-SQL in SQL Server

Comment: rit its related to sql server db @smn_onrocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think Its work**

@Ezlo code work properly but add the missing second paramater given below:

```
COALESCE([1],NULL,'0') as [1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The most natural function to use is `COALESCE()` because it is the ANSI-standard function for this purpose.  Under some circumstances in SQL Server, `ISNULL()` has better performance, but this is not one of those circumstances.

In the code, this looks like:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max),
        @colnames nvarchar(MAX),
        @query nvarchar(MAX);


select @cols = stuff((select ',' + QUOTENAME(Week) 
                      from pivote_created
                      group by Week
                      order by Week FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
                    );

select @colnames = stuff((select ', COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(Week) + ', ''0'') as ' + QUOTENAME(Week)
                      from pivote_created
                      group by Week
                      order by Week FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''
                    );

set @query =  'select ' + @colnames + '
               from (select store, week, xCount from pivote_created
                    ) src
               pivot (sum(xcount)for week in (' + @cols + ')
                     ) piv';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: This is the solution, but you are missing the 2nd (default) parameter of the coalesce when you build @colnames.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle, you can use `NVL` Function.

```
select NVL(xCount, 0) from dual
```

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `IsNull` function:

```
select ISNULL(xCount, 0)
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, then use the ISNULL function for the same effect.

Comment: This question was tagged as Oracle, it seems like it is updated. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply@ Pelin,                                                                   but IsNull () is not work in query i have tried

Comment: Can you please share the query that you tried? did you get an error?

Comment: ISNULL(SUM(xCount),0)
OR
SUM(ISNULL(xCount),0)                                                                                Error :  Incorrect syntax near 'ISNULL'.

Comment: select * from ( select store, week, ISNULL(xCount, 0) from pivote_created ) src pivot (sum(xcount)for week in (' + @col + ')) piv

Comment: @pelin thankx bt got this error : No column name was specified for column 3 of 'src'

Comment: can you please try again with using alias names?